# Consuming an operation with no body using camel-cxf-endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel, cxf, producer-consumer

I have a source web service which has an operation which does not take any body as a request. This is the request it expects:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body/>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have a consumer service that calls this operation using camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint. The endpoint is configured to have the dataFormat as "Payload". Something like this:

```
<camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint
        address="SOURCE_ENDPOINT"
        id="abcEndpoint" serviceClass="PATH_TO_GENERATED_SERVICE_CLASS">
        <camel-cxf:properties>
            <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD"/>
        </camel-cxf:properties>
        <camel-cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref component-id="wss4jOutInterceptor"/>
        </camel-cxf:outInterceptors>
    </camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

I am setting the body as null while calling this operation, expecting the CXFInterceptor to wrap the body with the SOAPEnvelope. However, when i am calling the service, I get :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The PayLoad elements cannot fit
>   with the message parts of the BindingOperation. Please check the
>   BindingOperation and PayLoadMessage

I checked the generated ServiceClass from the source wsdl to check if the operation expects any body. Here is the method it expects:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "SomeOperation", action = "SomeOperation")
    @WebResult(name = "Result", targetNamespace = "namespace_for_the_service", partName = "data")
    public Result someOperation();
```

I also tried using an XSLT to transform into an XML which does not add any elements but that does not solve anything. Am I missing something? Is it because of the dataFormat which is Payload ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by creating an empty CxfPayload:

```
List<Source> elements = new ArrayList<Source>();
CxfPayload<SoapHeader> cxfPayload = new CxfPayload<SoapHeader>(null, elements, null);
exchange.getIn().setBody(cxfPayload);
```

This worked for me!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't your SOAP envelope need to contain a minimal body with at least the target invoked method ?

```
<soap:Body>
    <m:SomeOperation xmlns:m="..."/>                 
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: Yes, so for this operation the wsdl:message has no part, something like this:

<wsdl:message name="SomeOperationIn" />